# Do CNNs benefit from HDR images?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, cnn

I have images with 12 bits per color channel which I use for several detection networks (YOLO, RetinaNet, etc.).
Can I expect any precision difference between 12 bpp and 8 bpp as network input? Or is it better to just scale the images down to 8 bpp?

Comment: Usually NN input is normalized, so probably overall effect would be not so dramatic. If 0 is minimum, 1 is maximum - for 12 bpp you'd have just more intermediate values, between these limits. I assume the effect is somewhat similar to feeding to a network colors it didn't encounter during training, and the result depends on the NN ability to generalize.

Comment: I would use 12 bpp images also for training. So the question also is, if the training benefits from the additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it depends on your images themselves and the task. So my short answer would be: for your task at hand, would this help a human being to perform the task? A similar answer may apply to your algorithm.

To be more specific: as far as I understand HDR compared to traditional images, the aim is to increase the dynamic range of the pictures to make it more similar to what the human eye sees. This means that for pictures with complex lighting conditions (strong backlighting for instance), there will be a real difference between classic / HDR pictures, so that if you aim at detecting objects in theses conditions, HDR will help.

On the other hand, if you have standard lighting conditions, I believe @mikalai answer fully applies and there will be not much difference.

I know this answer relates more to the "photography" side of the question rather than the machine learning side, but I think it is important to consider both in your case.

Does this help?

Comment: Shortly speaking, if the HDR image contains information that is absent in its 8-bit counterpart, it will be helpful, of course. This is true not only for CNN, but for any model.